# Standard normal random variable and definition of $\Phi$

Tags: probability, integration

Referencing the image below (the 2nd equation),

[image]

---

Is $$\Phi(x) = \int^x_{-\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}u^2\right) \, du$$ a standard definition? Or is it something defined just for this example? If its not a standard definition, how do I know to define this expression and not something else?

Comment: The upper limit on the integral for $\Phi(x)$ should be $x$, not $\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^x$, not $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty$.  Otherwise this supposed function of $x$ doesn't depend on $x$.

It is a standard definition.

Comment: Oh, yes this is a typo ... but the qn still remains, is it a standard definition or something created just to solve the problem?

Comment: And his answer remains: "It is a standard definition".

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution